# Как распаковать данные пакета GamePacket протокола RakNet?

Tags: python, zlib

Я хочу распаковать поле body из пакета GamePacket (0xfe).
Если верить [этой](https://wiki.vg/Raknet_Protocol#Game_Packet) странице, оно сжато.
Имею вот такие данные:

```
b'\x06\xc1\x01\x00\x00\x02F'
```

Пробую это:

```py
zlib.decompress(data)
```

Ошибка:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Пробую это:

```py
zlib.decompress(data, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

Ошибка:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type
```

Использую библиотеку `zlib` и `python`.

UPD: Попробовал добавить в начало байты `b"\x78\x9c"`, результат:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid stored block lengths
```

Answer (score 0):

В *RakNet* информация  может быть разделена на несколько пакетов данных, если пакет не может быть отправлен из-за ограничения MTU.

Если же пакет соответствует размеру MTU, как вижу, в вашем случае был скорее всего последний кусок цепочки пакетов, поэтому вылезла ошибка неверного заголовка, можете подробнее поискать по этому информацию, мне будет сложно объяснить.

У пакета данных есть информация, разделён ли он, если разделён по частям, тогда есть `split id` и `split index`.

Если пакет не разделён, то будет присутствовать байт 78, поэтому визуально можно определить, разделён ли пакет данных или нет.

Comment: Хочу дополнить свой ответ тем, что если пакет не разделён, то будет присутствовать байт 78, поэтому визуально можно определить разделён ли пакет данных или нет